# Simulate transaction before sending

Tags: transactions, unsigned

So lets say I have an unsigned transaction. Is there any way I can simulate the transaction without actually sending it to the chain to see if the transaction will fail or if it will be succesfull? Basically something like `estimateGas` on EVM chains.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [validate_transaction](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_transaction_pool/runtime_api/trait.TaggedTransactionQueue.html#method.validate_transaction) by calling into the runtime api using the client that you can get handle from outer node

or

from https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer -> developer -> Runtime calls -> taggedTransactionQueue -> validate_transaction .

Comment: Can I do this via polkadotjs?

Comment: @TadejVengust yes, what didn't you understood with my answer regarding using polkadotjs?

Comment: By polkadot js I ment polkadot SDK so progamatically via javascript.

Comment: @TadejVengust https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/runtime#taggedtransactionqueue

Comment: I tried to implement this but it don't quite understand the parameters. This expects 3 parameters which are:
- source (local, inBlock, external)
- tx
- blockHash

I want to verify if a transaction will be successful or not. Don't understand why I would need to provide a block hash? Can't find any docs or examples of the usage. Can you provide some?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an RPC call to [Dry run](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/rpc/#dryrunextrinsic-bytes-at-blockhash-applyextrinsicresult) an extrinsic at a given block. You can construct this with PolkadotJS very easily with `tx.dryRun`, see an example here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2913/2762

However this is an [unsafe RPC call](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/6298) and not all the nodes has it activated, if you are running your own node you can activate it with a flag: [Unsafe RPC calls?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/unsafe-rpc-calls)

You can use [Sidecar](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2912/2762) too that exposes an endpoint to dry run a extrinsic.